# Is T an instance of a template in C++?

Tags: c++, templates

Suppose I'm in a template and I want to know if a type parameter T is an instantiation of a particular template, e.g., `std::shared_ptr`:

```
template<typename T>
void f(T&& param)
{
    if (instantiation_of(T, std::shared_ptr)) ...   // if T is an instantiation of 
                                                    // std::shared_ptr...
  ...
}
```

More likely I'd want to do this kind of test as part of a std::enable_if test:

```
template<typename T>
std::enable_if<instantiation_of<T, std::shared_ptr>::type
f(T&& param) 
{
    ...
}

// other overloads of f for when T is not an instantiation of std::shared_ptr
```

Is there a way to do this? Note that the solution needs to work with all possible types and templates, including those in the standard library and in other libraries I cannot modify. My use of `std::shared_ptr` above is just an example of what I might want to do.

If this is possible, how would I write the test myself, i.e., implement `instantiation_of`?

Comment: Totally unrelated: the more pedantically correct name for `instantiation_of` is `specialization_of`.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes - so `typedef std::shared_ptr<int> IntPtr` is a specialization?

Comment: Yes, I know, but I was afraid that using that terminology would have confused more than clarified. I apologize if my fear was the the truly confusing factor.

Comment: @Useless yes. Informally, we often use "instantiation" to mean "specialization" and "specialization" to mean "explicit specialization", but technically, both are specializations.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: And the whole issue is further confounded because "explicit instantiation" is yet another thing that exists.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A partial spec should be able to do it.

```
template <template <typename...> class X, typename T>
struct instantiation_of : std::false_type {};

template <template <typename...> class X, typename... Y>
struct instantiation_of<X, X<Y...>> : std::true_type {};
```

http://ideone.com/4n346

I actually had to look up the template template syntax, because I've basically never had cause to use it before.

Not sure how this interacts with templates like `std::vector` with additional defaulted arguments.

Comment: Just use `template <typename...> class X` as your first argument and `typename ...Y` as your second.

Comment: @Kerrek: Thanks! I've no skill in variadic templates as MSVC does not support.

Comment: (And then it's `X<Y...>` -- sorry.)

Comment: (To explain: If you pass `T = std::vector<int>`, and `X = std::vector`, then `Y` is deduced as the pack `{ int, std::allocator<int> }`).

Comment: @DeadMG: I don't think this works, because I don't want to pass in the template arguments in the true case, I just want to pass in the type.  For example, If I have MySet as a typedef for std::set<int, mycomparitor, myallocator>, I want to get true from is_instantiation<set, MySet>.  [Kindly pardon the lousy formatting.  I can't figure out how to get code in a comment.  This is my first experience with SO.]

Comment: @user1426649: This should provide `true` in that case and [ideone](http://ideone.com/VOwkg) agrees. The success parameters are deduced, not explicit. Also, for code in comments, use backticks.

Comment: Yes, this works, thanks for the code.  The only minor wrinkle is that the query form supported by this code is `instantiation_of<_template_, _type_>` rather than the more natural (IMO) `instantiation_of<_type_, _template_>`.  This is easily fixed, as the solution by bstamour demonstrates.  Thanks again. [Hmmm, comment help notwithstanding, it seems that italics in code is not supported, sigh.]

Comment: @user1426649: When someone posts a correct answer, you should mark it as such with the tick thing next to it.

Comment: @DeadMG: In this case, there are two correct answers, but it does not seem to be possible to mark both as correct.  What is the protocol in that case?

Comment: @user1426649: Usually, you pick one that you think is higher quality or was created first or some other criterion. Ultimately, you are the questioner and it is your right to choose whatever answer you deem fit.

Comment: @DeadMG: But presumably not my right to deem multiple answers equally valid. Sigh. If only life were so simple as to have exactly one correct answer to every question.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12000/discussion-between-user1426649-and-deadmg)

Answer (score 11):

Why use `enable_if` when simple overloading suffices?

```
template<typename T>
void f(std::shared_ptr<T> param) 
{
    // ...
}
```

If you really do need such a trait, I think this should get you started (only roughly tested with VC++ 2010):

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename>
struct template_arg;

template<template<typename> class T, typename U>
struct template_arg<T<U>>
{
    typedef U type;
};

template<typename T>
struct is_template
{
    static T* make();

    template<typename U>
    static std::true_type check(U*, typename template_arg<U>::type* = nullptr);
    static std::false_type check(...);

    static bool const value =
        std::is_same<std::true_type, decltype(check(make()))>::value;
};

template<
    typename T,
    template<typename> class,
    bool Enable = is_template<T>::value
>
struct specialization_of : std::false_type
{ };

template<typename T, template<typename> class U>
struct specialization_of<T, U, true> :
    std::is_same<T, U<typename template_arg<T>::type>>
{ };
```

Comment: Sorry, I should have declared the function parameter to be of type T&& to clarify that I wanted to be able to perfect-forward the parameter.  I've edited the original post to show this.  With this constraint in place, overloading is not an option.

Comment: @user1426649: I don't see how perfect-forwarding invalidates this answer.

Comment: @MooingDuck: The only parameters that can be perfect-forwarded are of type T&&.  Types like std::shared_ptr<T>&& don't qualify.

Comment: @Mooing Duck:  Because if you have a function that accepts 'shared_ptr<T>&&', it cannot bind to an lvalue, where as 'T&&' can , because the way it decomposes during template argument deduction.

Comment: @user1426649 : Edited for a non-variadic approach.

Answer (score 3):

Best way to do it when dealing with a T&& is to make sure you remove_reference before doing the check, because the underlying type T can be a reference or a value type, and template partial specialization has to be exact to work. Combined with an answer above the code to do it could be:

```
template <
  typename T,
  template <typename...> class Templated
> struct has_template_type_impl : std::false_type {};

template <
  template <typename...> class T,
  typename... Ts
> struct has_template_type_impl<T<Ts...>, T> : std::true_type {};

template <
  typename T, 
  template <typename...> class Templated
> using has_template_type = has_template_type_impl<
    typename std::remove_reference<T>::type,
    Templated
>;
```

And then you just enable_if your way to victory:

```
template <typename T>
typename std::enable_if<has_template_type<T, std::shared_ptr>::value>::type
f(T&& param)
{
  // ...
}
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could be of some help ;)